# NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null. (Flutter)

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am running my Flutter app and getting this error:

```
The method '[]' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: []("id")
```

This is My User Class:-

```
class User {

final String id;
final String username;
final String email;
final String photoUrl;


User({
  this.id,
  this.username,
  this.email,
  this.photoUrl,
});

 factory User.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
   return User(
    id: doc.data()['id'],
    username: doc.data()['username'],
    email: doc.data()['email'],
    photoUrl: doc.data()['photoUrl'],

    );
  }
}
```

The Document in the database isn't null,
What Could Be Causing This Problem ??

Comment: Did you try printing ```doc.data()``` during code execution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
 factory User.fromDocument(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
   if(doc.data() == null){
      return User();
   }
   return User(
    id: doc.data()['id'],
    username: doc.data()['username'],
    email: doc.data()['email'],
    photoUrl: doc.data()['photoUrl'],
    );
  }
```

Comment: No, it Doesn't work I am just getting the Error "The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Map<String, dynamic> Function()'.
Try defining the operator '[]'. "

Comment: @SaiPrashanth I updated my answer, the reason may be the DocumentSnapshot  is `null`

Comment: It Worked But I had to edit doc == null to doc.data() == null